# Android Hero denies XMLSocket or Socket connection? ....errors #2031, #2048

Tags: flash

I am trying to adapt an existing flash web chat application for the Android mobile phone and I am having this really annoying issue. The server is a custom based solution and can send back both binary messages or XML. So I can use either XMLSocket class or the Socket class to get data from the server. Everything works fine when deployed and I connect from the desktop but when I try it from the android mobile I get the infamous errors #2031, followed by #2048. Now the crossdomain.xml file is rock solid and works well for desktop. When the connect socket method runs I see that the server replies with the crossdomain file but I get the error when running on the mobile. Has anyone bumped into this? Is there some limitation from the mobile phone part. I wasn't able to find anything relevant for this issue, in terms of the phone not allowing Socket or XMLSocket connections.

The phone(s) Motorola and HTC run Android 2.1 and indicates the flash FL10,1,123,358 version of flash lite. The issue can be reproduced also on the HTC Desire.

Any input on this would be highly appreciated...
10x,
Claudiu

Comment: I don't know the solution, but I think including the actual error statements rather than just error numbers might be helpful to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the *AIR* application descriptor has the right permissions as well:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

In the  tag:

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions>
        <manifest>
            <![CDATA[
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERMISSION_NAME" />
            ]]>
        </manifest>
    </manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

HTH,

J

Comment: @Amarghosh - the error text is something like this:
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: XX.XXX.XXX.XX, which is not incredibly helpful. Most of the times happens when server is lacking a policy file which is not the case here.

@Zárate - We cannot deploy the app as AIR since the phones only run Android 2.1. (By the way when I run it in the android simulator as Air app, it works just fine). The thing is I need to run it from browser for these older phones...